# Reset object in root View Controller from child view controller

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

My app has 4 view controllers. The first VC instantiate an object and has a "strong" ownership of it. Each VC passes it down to their respective child VC, they all have a weak relationship to that object. When the last VC is done and I do a 
    popToRootViewController 
I want the last VC to reset this object so that the first can have a new empty object to work with, how do i achieve this? I've tried setting the object to nil and alloc init a new object to the object but sadly, that doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate. Set second VC (ie, first child of root) to have a property called delegate (or parent, etc) that is set to point to the parent. Rather than adjusting it through your weak reference, tell the parent to release it, then pop.

Alternatively, if you don't want everyone to have to know the parent, you could access the top view controller directly via `UIApplicationDelegate`, assuming it has a property for the VC. In fact, you could put a reference to your shared object there, and reset it directly.

Comment: But if im 4 controllers deep, I will have to pass the delegate the entire way, that feels unintuitive.

Comment: @nevva - See edit - a few other possibilities using UIApplicationDelegate.